# laravel json output with foreign key data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Consider this JSON which returns a course information.

```
{
id: 1, 
user_id: 1,  
course_category_id: 5,
course_title: "PHP Programming Language",
course_requirment: "Need to Know HTML CSS and Object Oriented  Programming",
promo_video: null,
published: 0,
created_at: "2016-08-04 16:14:39",
updated_at: "2016-08-04 16:14:39"
}
```

I am passing a user_id and course_category_id. Instead of passing the user_id and course_category_id, I want to pass the user name and course_category name like we do in our blade files ($course->user->name). They are on different table.
user_id has a relationship with User model. So the method in Course Model is

```
public function user()
{ 
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
}
```

and for course_category_id,

```
public function course_cateogory()
{
   $return $this->belongsTo(CourseCategory::class);
}
```

in my controller:

```
$course = Course::where('user_id',1)->where('course_category_id',5)->first();
  return response()->json($course,200);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "how can I do it?" Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @NoobCoder Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas`. See **Querying Relationship Existence** section in the [Eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Example:

```
$posts = Course::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', 'name to search');
})->whereHas('course_category', function ($query) {
    $query->where('course_name', 'like', 'course name to search');
})->get();
```